# How to make yahoo like button using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, button, yahoo

I want to know how to create yahoo mail like button (for example their: Check Mail button). I would like to know if it's possible to create a similar button using jquery.  Please provide step by step details for this as I am novice with jQuery and web development in general.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct that you don't NEED jquery...but Jquery UI has a neat set of effects for buttons that are very easy to use and can be re-styled using the ThemeRoller plugin in no time flat.

See the tutorial here:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/

In a nutshell:  Include Jquery UI in your page...don't forget to also include the CSS for ThemeRoller.  Create an input (or link, etc) and apply the following class:  class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"  Voila--rounded corners, gradients, color styling, hover, etc.

Pretty easy, huh?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're goning to need jQuery. Any button I can think of can be acheived through CSS3 quite happily.

We'd also appreciate an image of the desired result, not everybody has a Yahoo mail account.

Comment: That's true, not everybody likes Yahoo.